# How to store permission binary sets

Tags: c#, database, enums, sql-server-2012, user-permissions

I am trying to find a way to store permission informations into a SQL Server 2012 Database.
My permissions are sets like this :

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionsB
{
    Aucun = 00000000,
    read = 00000001,
    write= 00000010,
    ssss = 00000100,
    tttt = 00001000,
    rrrr = 00010000,
}
```

And I can't find a way to store into the database, let's say, 00000011 that allows one to have access to read/write some stuff in my program. I do have an int column ready to store that but can't figure out how ot use it yet.

Comment: So is this question just about storing an int value in your database? Or do you not know how to convert your enum value to an int? Can you be more specific about your problem?

Comment: in fact your binary flags aren't binary, you should use 0x prefix to the decimal number to save it as binary, you could just do an OR operation to add the permissions together in one binary number and store it in your database

Comment: @CME64 `0x` is hex, not binary.

Comment: Are you using the permissions as flags, i.e. the values can be combined to allow read/write? If so, and depending on your intended usage on the SQL side, you may want to consider storing the values separately so that you can get (more of) the benefits of indexes. If you access the individual bits in a `WHERE` clause by masking them off from an integer column then the evaluation will proceed [RBAR](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Row_By_Agonizing_Row-%28RBAR%29.html).

Comment: Don't know how to convert the enum value to an int into the Database.
Yes, the permission are used as flags.

Comment: @JoeEnos yes you're right and it was my mistake saying "decimal number" and "as binary", but hex is easier to handle in representing binary than dec as its base is of the 2s multiples as it is with binary, the numbers the op used were integer in the form of binary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionsB
{
    Aucun = 0,
    read = 1,
    write= 2,
    ssss = 4,
    tttt = 8,
    rrrr = 16,
}
```

or using C# 7 numeric literal syntax, which might improve readability:

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionsB
{
    Aucun= 0b00000,
    read = 0b00001,
    write= 0b00010,
    ssss = 0b00100,
    tttt = 0b01000,
    rrrr = 0b10000,
}
```

Then as Jeffrey said, you should use bitwise operations:

```
PermissionsB permission = PermissionsB.read | PermissionsB.write;
```

the value that you will store is an integer, you can cast it directly:

```
int intPermission = (int) permission;
```

To restore the saved permissions you can simply do like this:

```
PermissionsB retrievedPermission = (PermissionsB) retrievedInteger;
```

To test the single permissions, just use bitwise operations:

```
bool canWrite = (retrievedPermission & PermissionsB.write) == PermissionsB.write;
```

Entity Framework (I think EF > 4.5 if I remember well) can manage trasparently the Enum types, so you don't need to cast to and from Integer in the database, I strongly recommend using EF if your back-end database is supported.

Comment: You forgot the `[Flags]`-Attribute

Comment: Alright, so I need to basically add the permission like this (for read+write permissions) :
PermissionsB permission = PermissionsB.read | PermissionsB.write;

Which is going to give me 3 and I store that int into the Database. How do I retrieve the separate permissions to test condition it in order to display the permission per user ?

Comment: Thanks for your time, I do use EF in my application. Saved me probably more than 1000 hours. 
Have a nice day man !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a bitwise or `|` on your enum.

```
PermissionsB permission = PermissionsB.read | PermissionsB.write;
```

See [Here for more information on enums in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

See [Here for very detailed information on using bitwise enums](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx)

Comment: Nice links thank you. How can I store that permission into a database ?

Comment: Just cast my example `permission` to an int and store it.